# Допустима ли многократная работа с ассоциативными массивами?

Tags: массивы, javascript

Допустима ли многократная работа с ассоциативными массивами?

```
var arr[key];
```

Где key - массив больших чисел (например, { 1234, 33412, 31235, 554235}).

Не знаю, как достать значения, кроме как использовать цикл for.
Из-за пустых значений массива работа скрипта не просядет по скорости?!

Comment: я не уверен, что можно использовать массив как ключ. Преобразовывайте в строку этот массив, так он гарантированно может быть ключём.

Но сама задача какая то странная. Переформулируйте.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что вы имеете в виду под многократной работой? В JavaScript нет ассоциативных массивов, есть просто массивы и объекты, которые ведут себя, как ассоциативные массивы. Если просто массивы с проходом по длине, то просядет. А если объекты как ассоциативные массивы, то цикл должен быть соответствующий:

```
var a = { 123:"cat", 65555:"dog" };
for(var property in a) {
    console.log(a[property]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Не понял вопроса.

Если надо достать элемент по конкретному индексу, например `31235`, то `arr[2];`

А также можно использовать ключ к индексу `var arr = {a : 1234, b : 33412, c : 31235, d : 554235}` где `arr.c` это `31235`.

А если же надо найти индекс, который соответствует этому числу, то без `for` не обойтись

```
var arr = [1234, 33412, 31235, 554235];
    for(i in arr) {
        if(arr[i] == 31235) {
            alert("found. iterator is: "+ i);
        }
    }
```